How to call the user defined function on IBM DB2
I have create a user defined function:
CREATE FUNCTION GetTotalSalesAmount (Product_ID char(6))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE total_sales DECIMAL(10, 2);
    SELECT SUM(Sales_Amount) INTO total_sales FROM Sales s WHERE s.Product_ID = Product_ID;
    RETURN total_sales;
END

And I try to call it by using SELECT GetTotalSalesAmount('ID2353') AS TotalSalesAmount;, I get some error SQL Error

[42601]: An unexpected token "END
SELECT GetTotalSalesAmount('ID23" was found following "ETURN total_sales".  Expected tokens may include:  "
".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.33.31

I don't know where wrong? Is my function create wrong or the call function I use wrong?

Please make sure you tag the product you are really using. DB2 and SQL Server are completely different products.

means when create the function i need to add the db2 name infront the function name like "CREATE FUNCTION DB2ADMIN.GetTotalSalesAmount (Product_ID char(6))" ?

I have no idea what that comment is trying to state (ask?).

Erm... Do you means that i need to specify what database system I using ?

" "END SELECT GetTotalSalesAmount('ID23" was found following "ETURN total_sales"." - that message makes it sound like you have that SELECT as part of the function definition.  Try generating the SQL for the function and see what it looks like, last line should be the END.

Does DB2 really accept SELECT without a FROM?

@jarlh not the version I use so that might be the issue too, it depends on what version for the dummy table to use.  YUZHANG CHIA - you need to tell use which variant of db2 you are using.

When asking for help with Db2, always write your Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud) because the answer can vary with the server-platform (and version, sometimes).  There are dedicated tags on stackoverflow for each Db2-server platform - use them.
In Db2 (all platforms), when you use the SELECT statement you always need to have a FROM clause. Your error happens because you do not show a FROM clause.
If your Db2-server platform is Z/OS mainframe then you can use a pseudo table called SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 , as the target of your FROM clause. You can also use this on other platforms (it may be implemented as a view with one row and one column).
If your Db2-server platform is Linux / Unix / Windows / cloud, you can use the VALUES statement instead of a SELECT statement, and the VALUES statement does not need a FROM clause. For example, on Db2-LUW, values(GetTotalSalesAmount('ID2353'))
